Expand a variable before a command in XeTeX
I'm trying to use a variable inside a command but the variable expand after the command so the command don't get the correct value.
The code is the following :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% package to open file containing variables
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{;}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\begin{document}%
    \isotope{24,\var{elNum}}        
\end{document}

The mydata.dat file has the following content :
elNum;12

And I got the following error :

test.tex: error: 20: Missing number, treated as zero. ^^I^^I\isotope{24,\elNum}

By the way, I need to compile with XeLaTeX but I don't think it's related to the problem.

No you just have mistyped the name 1 m or 2

I didn't put a correct MWE, so it was not possible to understand my problem really. I described it again editing the post.

The problem comes with the order of expansion of the \var command and the \isotope command I think.

Your \var{elNum} is a series of instructions for printing something; it doesn't expand to 12 as you're expecting. By the way, defining \elNumm is completely useless, because you'd get the same from \isotope{24,\var{elNum}}. Anyway, without a short version of mydata.dat we can do little for helping you.

what do you mean by a short version ?
The file mydata.dat is just "elNum;12".
I posted it in the post when I updated it.

About using \isotope{24,\var{elNum}}, it's what I used first and I tried using a variable to solve the problem but as you say, it's useless.

we can't compile your code. it doesn't have e.g. a document class. if \DTLfetch is expandable, \edef might work.

You're right, it was hidden. Now it's visible.
But still not working.
I modified the code to take out \elNumm as it was useless

I even tried changing everything in lowercase as \elnum and the problem is still the same.

@guiné: You need to store \var{elNum} first, then use that. So, you need something like \newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpval}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}} and then use \var{elNum} \isotope{24, \tmpval}.

@werner It works like a charm ! Thanks a lot.

\isotope needs its arguments expanded, which is not the case when you use \var as-is. Instead, update it to pull the relevant information and store it is some temporary macro. Then you can pass that to \isotope.
The minimal example below wraps the above discussion up into \Isotope:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.dat}
elNum;12
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}

\NewDocumentCommand{\var}{ m }{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpval}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Isotope}{ m m }{%
  \var{#2}% Retrieve key associated with #1
  \isotope{#1,\tmpval}%
}

\begin{document}%

\Isotope{24}{elNum}

\end{document}

If you want to use a mixture of isotope arguments, you could condition on whether the arguments supplied is integer or not via \DTLifint:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.dat}
elNum;12
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}

\NewDocumentCommand{\varA}{ m }{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpvalA}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\varB}{ m }{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpvalB}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Isotope}{ m m }{%
  \DTLifint{#1}{\def\tmpvalA{#1}}{\varA{#1}}% Condition on #1 being a number or a value to extract
  \DTLifint{#2}{\def\tmpvalB{#2}}{\varB{#2}}% Condition on #2 being a number or a value to extract
  \isotope{\tmpvalA,\tmpvalB}% Set isotope
}

\begin{document}%

\Isotope{24}{elNum}

\Isotope{elNum}{24}

\Isotope{elNum}{elNum}

\Isotope{24}{24}

\end{document}


It's working perfectly but how would you do it if both values of Isotope where stored in the file ? And calling something like \Isotope{elMass}{elNum} ?

@guiné: Do you have mixtures of components of the isotope inputted manually and from the data set? So, in your document you might have a combination of \Isotope{<num>}{<name>}, \Isotope{<name>}{<num>}, \Isotope{<name>}{<name>}, \Isotope{<num>}{<num>}?

Yes, I do. I have sometimes only one needed from the data set but the problem is when I need both from data set.

@guiné; See the updated answer.
