Expand a variable before using \ch from \chemfig
I'm trying to use a variable inside a command but the variable expand after the command so the command don't get the correct value.
I aksked a similar question there for the \isotope command but the solution doesn't seem to work in this case : Expand a variable before a command in XeTeX
The code is the following :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% package to open file containing variables
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{;}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\newcommand{\varT}[1]{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpval}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}}
\begin{document}%
    \ch{\var{molecule}}
    \varT{molecule}\ch{\tmpval}
\end{document}

The mydata.dat file has the following content :
molecule;NH2

And when compiling, I get NH2 instead of NH2
By the way, I need to compile with XeLaTeX but I don't think it's related to the problem.

isn't this identical to your last question you \var function is not expandable, you need to extact the data into an expandable macro. then use it

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727142/expand-a-variable-before-a-command-in-xetex#comment1810035_727142

I did that and it doesn't work with \ch, I don't know why.

You say the solution did not work, in which case you should show what you tried (using \tmpvar as suggested in the solution provided in the comment.

I edited (sorry for not doing it right the first time).

note I made a cosmetic update to my answer just after you accepted (I am not sure if the system alerts you)


You need an expandable command, and you need to expand it first:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% package to open file containing variables
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{;}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
%\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\newcommand{\varT}[1]{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpval}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#1}}
\newcommand{\varTT}[2]{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmpval}{thevalue}{mydata}{thekey}{#2}\expandafter#1\expandafter{\tmpval}}
\begin{document}%

% this works but looks messy   \varT{molecule}\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\tmpval}

\varTT\ch{molecule}

\end{document}


You can define your own \loaddb command which declared simply expandable \var using \csname and \endcsname primitives. You don't need to use the datatool package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
% package to open file containing variables

\def\loaddb#1{% 
   \setbox0=\vbox{
   \endlinechar=`^^J
   \everypar={\loaditem}
   \input{#1}
   }%
}
\def\loaditem #1;#2^^J{\expandafter\gdef \csname var.#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\var#1{\csname var.#1\endcsname} % it simply expands to the value

% import data
\loaddb{mydata.dat}

\begin{document}%
  Try \expandafter\ch\expanded{{\var{molecule}}}
\end{document}


I'll look into it.
